# Drawing Text onto Panel similar to MS Paint

Tags: c#, paint, rectangles, drawtext

I am in the process of learning C# as I am most familiar with C++ so if there is a simple answer to this question please forgive me. Also thank you for taking the time to read this, I appreciate it!!! :)

I am currently in the process of creating a program similar to MS Paint. I would like to be able to draw text on a panel. I've found the .DrawString() which can apparently be used to do exactly this, though in all of the examples I've seen they have coordinates predefined and do not allow the user to choose where to place it. I want this to be similar to MS Paint by allowing  the user to click and drag to make the size of the box the text shall appear in. I am not concerned about allowing them to move the text around once the rectangle is drawn with the text.

I was originally thinking to have them type their string into a textbox and then draw it onto a rectangle so they could size it appropriately to fit their string since the string should wrap inside of the rectangle. So I have two questions:

1. How can I have the text wrap around the rectangle and obviously cut
   off anything that does not fit (again similar to MS Paint)?
2. By drawing a rectangle (if my idea is plausible of course) it will
   leave a border around the text since it is making a rectangle. I do
   not want this border, I only want the text. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You note the location where the user clicks and there you draw. the drawstring has a format that lets you pass in a layout rectangle. but first of all: do read up the winforms drawing model!!

Comment: Thanks, it was stupidly easy. I didn't realize at the time that it would draw the text in a rectangle for you in the chosen color without a border. When I realized it I was pretty darn embarrassed that I asked such an easy question.